# How to show all the posts under the same Year in a page WordPress?

Tags: archives

is it possible to show the posts of the same year in a page and the post with different year in other pages. If Yes, then how?

Comment: WordPress already does this out of the box with date archives, available in years/months/days

Comment: @TomJNowell I am making custom template, i don't know how to implement this in my code.

Comment: You don't have to, if you want to customise the template you can use the provided template files, e.g. `date.php` `year.php` etc in your theme, you don't need a page template. Just use a standard main loop and it will just work, e.g. `example.com/2019`. Otherwise you can query for posts by year easily using the provided parameter for `WP_Query` listed in the docs